# Use Firebase Admin JS SDK to impersonate users programmatically for server side rendering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, server-side-rendering, firebase-admin

I'm trying to do server side rendering with Firebase and am struggling with using the Admin SDK to impersonate a uid so that all database security rules are followed as if the request came from an authenticated user with the same uid. I'm aware of the databaseAuthVariableOverride functionality in initializeApp, but that only works for a single initialization, not a potentially enormous amount per second. Anyone have a totally different approach or suggestions for me?

Here's the equivalent of what I would like to do:

```
const getAdminAsUser = (authorizedUid) => firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(adminConfig),
    databaseURL: firebaseConfig.databaseURL,
    databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
        uid: authorizedUid,
    },
});
```